# JQuery AJAX Call not returning Sucess function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a super simple JQuery ajax request below:

```
$.ajax("../ajax/data/items.json",
{ success: setContent, type: "GET", dataType: "json" });

function setContent(data, status, jqxhr) {

alert("Hello!");
}
```

The json loads on the page with a 200 response. The success function is set to setContent(). But the success function never runs and I cannot figure out why.

**Questions:**

1. Is my understanding of how the success function works incorrect? Why doesn't the function setContent() run for a 200 response on the Json?
2. Are the arguments for setContent() filled out behind the scenes by JQuery? Obviously I am not setting it anywhere in the code, but the video does not show adding arguments any place.

I am following Lynda.com's tutorial:

http://www.lynda.com/jQuery-tutorials/AJAX-made-simple/183382/368483-4.html

specifically the video AJAX made Simple.

Comment: As always, when you aren't getting the `success` handler called, install an `error` handler and see what it tells you the error is.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely that you aren't getting back valid JSON.  If you specify the data type as JSON and it returns something else, the success handler will not get called.

There is nothing wrong with the syntax:

[image]

As you can see, the console.log fires if you don't specify the dataType, as it doesn't care if it is JSON or not.  If you do specify, nothing gets logged.

```
$.ajax(window.location.href,
{ success: setContent, type: "GET", dataType: "json" });

function setContent(data, status, jqxhr) {

console.log("It worked!");
}
```

You can copy that into dev tools on this site and see what happens when you remove the dataType parameter.

Comment: This seems like a likely possibility.  It's a guess, but a likely possibility.  The way to tell for sure is (as I've suggested in a comment) is for the OP to install an `error` handler for the Ajax call and see what the actual error is.  If it's a JSON error that will show in the error handler.